# Understanding fold() and its impact on gremlin query cost in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to understand query costs in Azure Cosmos DB

I cannot figure out what is the difference in the following examples and why using fold() lowers the cost:

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').project('itemId', 'id').by('itemId').by('id')
```

which produces the following output:

```
[
  {
    "itemId": 14,
    "id": "186de1fb-eaaf-4cc2-b32b-de8d7be289bb"
  },
  {
    "itemId": 5,
    "id": "361753f5-7d18-4a43-bb1d-cea21c489f2e"
  },
  {
    "itemId": 6,
    "id": "1c0840ee-07eb-4a1e-86f3-abba28998cd1"
  },           
....    
  {
    "itemId": 5088,
    "id": "2ed1871d-c0e1-4b38-b5e0-78087a5a75fc"
  }
]
```

The cost is 15642 RUs x 0.00008 $/RU = 1.25$

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').project('itemId', 'id').by('itemId').by('id').fold()
```

which produces the following output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "itemId": 14,
      "id": "186de1fb-eaaf-4cc2-b32b-de8d7be289bb"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 5,
      "id": "361753f5-7d18-4a43-bb1d-cea21c489f2e"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 6,
      "id": "1c0840ee-07eb-4a1e-86f3-abba28998cd1"
    },
...
    {
      "itemId": 5088,
      "id": "2ed1871d-c0e1-4b38-b5e0-78087a5a75fc"
    }
  ]
]
```

The cost is 787 RUs x 0.00008$/RU = 0.06$

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').values('id', 'itemId')
```

with the following output:

```
[
  "186de1fb-eaaf-4cc2-b32b-de8d7be289bb",
  14,
  "361753f5-7d18-4a43-bb1d-cea21c489f2e",
  5,
  "1c0840ee-07eb-4a1e-86f3-abba28998cd1",
  6,
...
  "2ed1871d-c0e1-4b38-b5e0-78087a5a75fc",
  5088
]
```

cost: 10639 RUs x 0.00008 $/RU = 0.85$

```
g.V().hasLabel('item').values('id', 'itemId').fold()
```

with the following output:

```
[
  [
    "186de1fb-eaaf-4cc2-b32b-de8d7be289bb",
    14,
    "361753f5-7d18-4a43-bb1d-cea21c489f2e",
    5,
    "1c0840ee-07eb-4a1e-86f3-abba28998cd1",
    6,
...
    "2ed1871d-c0e1-4b38-b5e0-78087a5a75fc",
    5088
  ]
]
```

The cost is 724.27 RUs x 0.00008 $/RU = 0.057$

As you see, the impact on the cost is tremendous.
This is just for approx. 3200 nodes with few properties.

I would like to understand why adding fold changes so much.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to reproduce your example, but unfortunately have opposite results (500 vertices in Cosmos):

```
g.V().hasLabel('test').values('id')
```

or

```
g.V().hasLabel('test').project('id').by('id')
```

gave respectively 
86.08 and 91.44 RU, while same queries followed by *fold()* step resulted in 585.06 and 
590.43 RU.

This result I got seems fine, as according to TinkerPop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#fold-step):

> There are situations when the traversal stream needs a "barrier" to
>   aggregate all the objects and emit a computation that is a function of
>   the aggregate. The fold()-step (map) is one particular instance of
>   this.

Knowing that Cosmos charge RUs for both number of accessed objects and computations that are done on those obtained objects (*fold* in this particular case), higher costs for fold is as expected.

You can try to run *executionProfile()* step for your traversal, which can help you to investigate your case. When I tried:

```
g.V().hasLabel('test').values('id').executionProfile()
```

I got 2 additional steps for *fold()* (same parts of output omitted for brevity), and this *ProjectAggregation* is where the result set was mapped from 500 to 1:

```
 ...
      {
        "name": "ProjectAggregation",
        "time": 165,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 8.2
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "QueryDerivedTableOperator",
        "time": 1,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 0.05
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        }
      }
...
```